# How do I add a default value to a key in etcd3 if one does not already exist?

Tags: etcd3

In etcd2, I could populate a default value as follows:

```
curl -Ss -XPUT "${ETCDCTL_PEERS}/v2/keys/mykey?prevExist=false" -d value=defaultValue
```

How can I achieve the same logic with etcdv3?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
etcdctl txn <<<'mod("my_key_exists") > "0"

get next_ip_value

put my_key_exists 1
put my_key "defaultValue"

'
```